# Redirect blog from subdomain to folder of domain, different hosting

Tags: linux, windows, iis, reverse-proxy

I have a `blog.domain.com/something` hosted on Linux and my main site hosted on Windows IIS - `domain.com`. I want to make my blog accessible on this path `domain.com/blog/something`, but still to point to my Linux machine.

I read that ARR is handy, but I don't know how to make it work with the redirection to folder instead of subdomain.

Any ideas are appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: Well, if you learned how to reverse proxy `http://something.com/webmail` to `http://localhost:8081` from Microsoft's article, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/extensions/url-rewrite-module/reverse-proxy-with-url-rewrite-v2-and-application-request-routing I believe you know how to handle your case.

Answer (score 0):

You could try to use the below rule:

```
<rule name="Proxy">
<match url="blog/(.*)"/>
<conditions>
<add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="domain.com" />
</conditions>
<action type="Rewrite" url="http://blog.domain.com/{R:1}" />
</rule>
```

Comment: Thanks for the info. Unfortunately, it's not working. What I need to do is to serve the content that is in the Linux machine with this subdomain - **blog.domain.com/something** -  to a subfolder of the main domain **domain.com/blog/something**.

Comment: @DianaRuse could you please explain in detail what is not working? did you try reverse proxy https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/extensions/url-rewrite-module/reverse-proxy-with-url-rewrite-v2-and-application-request-routing?

Comment: I installed ARR on IIS, I enabled it, I added my blog server in Server Farms, at the server level an automatic URL Rewrite rule was created named ARR_blog_loadbalance which routes to Server Farm - my blog. When this rule is configured with Wildcards and "*" for the pattern, I can see that whenever I access domain.com, I'm redirected to blog.domain.com. But I don't want to redirect my main site, just a subfolder that currently doesn't exist. So, I modified the pattern to "domain.com/blog/*" to route to my Server Farm. And it's not working. Nothing happens.

Comment: Then probably I'll need another URL rewrite rule for redirecting blog.domain.com to domain.com/blog...because I want my content from blog.domain.com Linux server to be displayed in my main site subfolder. I hope it makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

The solution was to create a virtual directory in IIS named *blog* under my domain.com site. The physical path for this virtual directory can be whatever. I put the default local directory to IIS default page.

ARR and its rule worked smoothly after.